# Getting data from Oracle sql from Kotlin microservice getting duplicate result

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc, kotlin

I am trying to get data from Oracle SQL database from Kotlin microservice. Oracle database has no primary key columns.

In my data class I have given annotation `@ID` for one of the parameters, since without it Spring is throwing error.
In my `Repository` class I am using `findByColumnname1` but it returns only duplicate JSON array. One record is repeating as per number of records in `select count(*) from tablename where columnname = Columnname1`.

I also tried to use @Query but same result.

Comment: Well, if you realy have two rows with `columnname= Columnname1`, why do you wonder  getting a "duplicated" result?

Comment: Yeah but problem is columns which have different values are coming as same,basically one row is getting duplicated

Comment: Please post some sample data which reproduces the problem, and also your code. However, you need to understand that the real problem is defining database tables without primary keys. Keys are fundamental to the correction operation of RDBMS systems, so having a bad data model will inevitably give you grief. Instead of trying to finagle Spring you should focus on fixing your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding @Id to all columns and making my entity class as Idclass.